# Extracting value from XML fails

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic

I have searched for many examples and tutorials about reading XML files, but I cannot extract value from a single XML document. I think I am confused about Value, SingleNode, Text etc. declarations.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resultObj>
  <result>False</result>
  <invoiceNumber>1</invoiceNumber>
  <invoiceDate>2016/05/18 08:26:35</invoiceDate>
</resultObj>
```

VBScript (with classic ASP) to read result:

```vb
Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDOM.async = False
xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlDOM.Load("file.xml")
Set myroot= xmlDOM.selectSingleNode("/resultObj/result")
response.write myroot.Text
```

Error on last line:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>   Object required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're actually running this code from an ASP page I'd suspect you have an issue loading the file (might not be in the current working directory of the web server process). Since both `Load` and `SelectSingleNode` will fail silently without raising an error you need to check the value of the `ParseError` property after loading the file:

```
xmlDOM.Load("file.xml")
If xmlDOM.ParseError <> 0 Then
  response.write xmlDOM.ParseError.Reason
Else
  response.write "file loaded"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I posted a new question relating to this. Please check if you can help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339797/loading-xml-file-from-httprequest-output