# Loading XML file from httprequest output

Tags: xml, vbscript, httprequest, msxml

I am trying to analyse the output of httprequest which is formatted as XML. I use MSXML2.DOMDocument to load the response as XML but I receive this error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

this is the output of httprequest when I receive it as **ResponseText**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resultObj>
  <result>False</result>
  <invoiceNumber>1</invoiceNumber>
  <referenceNumber>21669145</referenceNumber>
  <transactionDate>2016/05/18 20:10:07</transactionDate>
</resultObj>
```

and this is my Vbscript code to load the result as XML file:

```
data= "invoiceUID=1"
Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
httpRequest.Open "POST", "https://some url", False
httpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpRequest.Send data

postResponse = httpRequest.ResponseXML.xml

Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDOM.async = False
xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlDOM.Load(postResponse) ///// I think this line fails

If xmlDOM.ParseError <> 0 Then
  response.write xmlDOM.ParseError.Reason
Else
  response.write "file loaded"
End If
```

Comment: Well, why don't you simply use `httpRequest.responseXML`? After all, the object is already the DOM representation of the parsed response, there is no need for you to parse it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the [`load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722(v=vs.85).aspx) method, which

> Loads an XML document from the specified location.

However you want to load the XML as a string into the object, so use [`loadXML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585(v=vs.85).aspx), which

> Loads an XML document using the supplied string.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find documentation about this. I did search for 2 days but no luck!

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I use the MSDN reference; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764730(v=vs.85).aspx