# How to request data from an XML-RPC endpoint in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, xml-rpc

Pre-first, VBScript is obviously an obsolete language.

First, I'm limited to VBScript because the script runs inside the Seagull Scientific BarTender 10.1 label printing app. I cannot install modules with NuGet or similar.

In VBScript, how is an XML-RPC request constructed and sent? The request is a [combination of XML and HTTP headers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml-rpc/xml_rpc_request.htm). What is required to format a XML-RPC request in VBScript, and what is required to convert the response XML to an object, similarly to the Python example below.

In Python

```
models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'res.partner', 'check_access_rights',
    ['read'], {'raise_exception': False})
```

My attempt in VBScript

```
Dim xmlRpcRequest, endpoint, method

Set xmlRpcRequest = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0") 
endpoint = "https://1.erp.practichem.dev/xmlrpc/2/common"
xmlReq = "execute_kw"
xmlRpcRequest.open "GET", endpoint, false
xmlRpcRequest.send

msgbox() = xmlRpcRequest.responseText
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading XML file from httprequest output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37339797)

Comment: Try not to ask too many questions as [so] questions should be specific problems not how to do this then do this. Asking multiple questions in the same question will lead to the question being closed as "Too broad".

Comment: @user692942, I had seen both before. I'm already doing what is shown in the first (HTTP GET), but I must also send the method `execute_kw`, which is abstracted in the Python class.

The second (Loading XML...) will be extremely helpful, thank you.

Comment: I am hoping there's some COM object or similar inbuilt functionality for VB for encoding a structure into XML-RPC

Comment: No, VBScript first came on the scene in 1996 followed by XML-RPC in 1998. There is no built-in support to parse XML-RPC structures but VBScript does give you the tools to build a parser yourself using the MSXML COM library.

Comment: @user692942, My question is not the same as "HTTP GET in VBS." HTTP GET is a method. XML-RPC is a remote procedure call language. Don't mark them as duplicate. SO exists to assist people with questions. You've shot down my question.

Comment: Not shooting you down, it's just VBScript pre-dates XML-RPC so there is no "built-in" support for it. But, it does have support for XHR requests (which [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204759/http-get-in-vbs) deals with) and the ability to parse XML responses. In basic terms, XML-RPC is still a type of XML response (see the [second duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37339797)), it's up to you to parse it as a valid XML-RPC structure.

Comment: As a side note the line `msgbox() = xmlRpcRequest.responseText` is invalid syntax, you probably wanted `msgbox xmlRpcRequest.responseText` see the [`MsgBox()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/sfw6660x(v=vs.84)) for more info.